# Why do SortedList and List use array and why is LinkedList not much used?

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, sortedlist

In my mind, `List` is basically implemented using `LinkedList`, while a normal `Array` is implemented as contiguous blocks. I always used `List` because it is in the `Generic` namespace and because I thought it used *dynamic memory allocation* - but I was wrong.

Yesterday I saw the implementation of `List` using Reflector and found it is actually an array of T(`T[]`). There are lots of `Array.Copy` around while manipulating each element in the `List`. For instance, when you use `Insert`, it will create a new memory and copy all the elements before/after the inserted elements. So it seem to me the use of `List` is very expensive.

I saw the `SortedList` as well. I am not sure why a `SortedList` also implements an array inside it. Don't you think `SortedList` would be horrible to use an array as you need to sort the list every time a minor manipulation to the `List` occurs?

I also wonder why `List` is so popular as most people use it rather than going for `LinkedList`. Is it only because of the flexibility of the indexer?

Comment: Look closer: List<> does *not* create a new array and copy all items on *each* call. The array is only resized when it's full, and it's resized to twice it's original size. The resizing occurs only at exponentially increasing intervals when continuously adding items.

Comment: There's not correct answer to this question. Think about either be more specific or mark as wiki

Comment: @dtb yes it uses this._items[this._size++] = item;
Yes it exponentially increasing intervals, but how does it always ensure that size++ does have an empty space ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The biggest reason is modern computer design.  The CPU cache is *very* important because RAM is so slow.  The memory bus design just couldn't keep up with the rapid advances in CPU clock speeds.  Making a high frequency digital signal travel more than an inch is very difficult.

An array has unbeatable cache performance, it very likely that the next element is already in the cache when you iterate it.  A linked list gives low odds that this is the case, the next item is essentially at a random address when items are added at a low rate.  That's expensive, it stalls the processor, waiting for the RAM to catch up.  Can be hundreds of cycles.

Comment: Yes, SortedList really looked to me expensive. 
I think I got my answer from you.
So the point is :

Array => Good because very next element is available instantly, giving away less workload to CPU.
LinkedList => Good when insert in middle, Not often required for me too. 
SortedList => Very expensive, should be avioided.

Comment: +1 very good point/explanation. And don't forget that you're even more slow if you have to access to previous element address when you need the next :)

Comment: @abhishek: SortedList has a different purpose. It is an associative collection (Key-Value), it is sorted by key and it has a quite fast O(log n ) key lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Because most collections don't need insertions into the middle often.  But they do need directly access via an indexer.

Comment: nailed it :) The best reason. Also, a `List<T>` is much simpler to use and understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an in-memory collection of a single-type for which:

1. The collection must be growable.
2. The most common mutation operation is *appending* an item to the end of the collection.
3. Fast retrieval by *index* is essential.

then `List<T>`is probably your best choice. `LinkedList<T>`may be a better choice when (2) and (3) do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

In real life *List* doesn't call *Array.Copy* often, usually you just append items to array, not insert. It's a purpose of *List*, in contrast to a linked list. You just should to choose a proper collection class.

If you insert items often use linked list. If you mostly add items and need to iterate them effectively, use *List*.